# I am able to debug on Iphone but the release file can not be opened on Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, release, ipa

The code cane be debugged but when I try to release it via MAC agent, it creates the IPA file on build server, but as soon as I open the app it is closed.

The  Launcher Storyboard is ok. For app icons and LaunchImages, I use Asset Catalog.

The Visual studio log shows this message:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.MetadataReader.IMetadataTables'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{D8F579AB-402D-4B8E-82D9-5D63B1065C68}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Do you have any guidance?

Thanks,